# How to display Google Maps on the remaining screen?

Tags: html, sass, ionic3

In my ionic 3 application, I want to display google map on all of the remaining screen.
But when I set height to 100%, the map doesn't show up.

The html and scss files are given as below, by setting height to 55%, the google map shows up but leaves a blank on the remaining screen.

html:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img [src]="item.profilepic"/>
    </ion-avatar>
    <p>Last Seen: {{lasttime}} </p>
    <p>Distance: {{distance}} km </p>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-buttons>
    <button ion-button block (click)="navme()"> NAVIGATE TO {{item.name}} </button>
  </ion-buttons>

  <div #map id="map" class="google-map"></div>
```

scss

```
.google-map{
  height: 55%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
.whatever is containg the map {
   position: relative;
}

.map-container {
  position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
}

.map {
   height: 100%;
}
```